# Se marcan dos valores en una matriz bidimensional C++

Tags: c++

Veran, tengo una matriz de 10 filas y 15 columnas, el programa es como los

asientos de un cine, el problema es que cuando convierto un "asiento" a ocupad

transforma el de la fila de arriba y 10 lugares a la derecha tambien en ocupado

dejo el codigo. La transformacion se realiza en una sola fila que incluye la

direccion del asiento que cambiar, pero sigue cambiando la otra.

Por ejemplo si cambio la posicion asiento[1][0] la posicion [0][10] cambia automaticamente a ocupado tambien, son matrices de strings usando |0 | como disponible y |X |como ocupado

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
string asientos[15][10];
void valinicial();

int main()
{
    valinicial();
    string letras[] = { "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J" };
    int cont = 1;
    string fila[10];
    int menu = 0;
    int x,y;
    string conv;
    do
    {
        cout << "SELECCIONE UNA OPCION" << endl;
        cout << "1- Comprar un asiento" << endl;
        cin >> menu;
        switch (menu)
        {
        case 1:
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Seleccione un asiento para comprar\n0 = Disponible\nX = Ocupado" << endl;
            while (cont <= 15)
            {
                if (cont < 10)
                {
                    cout << "   " << cont;
                    cont++;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "  " << cont;
                    cont++;
                }
            }
            cout << "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cout << letras[i] << " ";
                for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                {
                    cout << asientos[i][j];
                }
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+\n";
            }
            cout << "Escriba la letra del asiento" << endl;
            cin >> conv;
            cout << "Escriba el numero del asiento" << endl;
            cin >> x;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (letras[i]==conv)
                {
                    y = i;
                    i = 11;
                }
            }
            asientos[y][x-1] = "|X| ";
            cont = 1;
            break;
        }
    } while (menu!=2);
}
void valinicial() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< 15; j++)
        {
            asientos[i][j] = "|0| ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si declaras la matriz tal que:

```
string asientos[15][10];
```

¿Por qué la recorres de esta manera?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j< 15; j++)
  {
      asientos[i][j] = "|0| ";
  }
}
```

Es decir, si `i` itera en el rango `0..10` y `j` lo hace en el rango `0..15` lo lógico sería usar `asientos[j][i]` y no al revés.

Las matrices de tamaño fijo, es decir, aquellas matrices cuyo tamaño viene determinado en tiempo de compilación, como es tu caso, se diferencian de las creadas usando memoria dinámica en que las diferentes filas ocupan posiciones contiguas de memoria. Si por ejemplo declarase una matriz de 2x3, en memoria se guardaría así:

```
 00 01 02 03 04 05
| fila 0 | fila 1 |
|c0 c1 c2|c0 c1 c2|
```

Por eso, la posición `[0,4]` es equivalente a la posición `[1,0]`.

Esto también pasa porque ni el compilador ni nadie va a comprobar si estás haciendo un uso correcto de la memoria de tu aplicación...únicamente el Sistema Operativo puede decidir matar tu aplicación si la misma intenta acceder a memoria que no pertenece a tu aplicación... pero la aplicación es libre de gestionar la memoria que tiene asignada como mejor le parezca.

Así que procura no invertir las coordenadas de fila y columna si no quieres tener resultados extraños en tu aplicación